# How can an autowired list of beans include classes not explicitly marked as Components?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

Imagine I have `@Component` classes `RefreshCmd` and `StartCmd` which extend an abstract class `Command`.

```
@Autowire
List<Command> commandList;
```

The list above is succesfully filled by Spring at runtime with `RefreshCmd` and `StartCmd`.

My issue is with beans which don't have their own exclusive class, let's assume:

```
@Configuration
//some class

@Bean
public SimpleCommand startCommand(){
    return new SimpleCommand("some arg", () -> some lambda);
}

@Bean
public SimpleCommand helpCommand(){
    return new SimpleCommand("some arg", () -> some lambda);
}
```

These beans are not included in the list. I want them to be included.

**How can method-defined beans (so without the possibility of annotating with `@Component`) be included in the list?**

One solution I found is to use `@Resource()` to autowire them to individual fields in another class and then add them to the list with `@PostConstruct` - this looks horrible and I'm looking for the correct way of doing things.

Comment: Try to avoid such phrasing as "*will not*" unless you have documentation to that effect. What you mean is "*does not*" (for you). Probably because something in your project is not configured properly. I've tested this and it works fine. Is SimpleCommand actually a Command?

Comment: @Michael Ok, sorry. For me, it does not work. Could you share your example with me? I don't understand what could be causing this, my code looks exactly like my question.

Comment: Does `SimpleCommand` extend or implement `Command`? This normally works without any problem.

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic- It does, yes. It extends the abstract class Command. Neither Command nor SimpleCommand have a Component annotation. 
All other sub-classes which are not declared as Bean methods have a Component annotation and are correctly added to the list at runtime.

Comment: Here https://github.com/michaelboyles/spring-example Output: "Got 3 commands: [...]" In future rather than ask someone to provide an example that prove that something works, why don't you provide an example that proves that it doesn't? Usually when I'm in the process of making such an example myself, that's when I realise what the mistake is.

Comment: @Michael thank you, although the issue is that your example solves a different problem. It creates a separate list component, it doesn't just autowire the list into a field. I cloned your example, removed the ListTarget class and added an autowired List<Command> field in the MyConfig class. Output: Got 1 commands. (Output printed in PostConstruct on MyConfig).

Comment: @Reneux You cannot have it both ways. You are trying to have MyConfig both consume commands AND produce more commands. If you add a field to MyConfig like what you're describing, that needs to be populated when MyConfig is instantiated. The extra beans that it produces can't be produced until after that's already done. Move that field to anywhere else and it will work fine.

Comment: @Michael thank you. If you post your comment as an answer I'll mark it as accepted. I don't feel it's necessarily intuitive that it should work this way for some who first comes across Spring. My own conclusion was that the injection order would've been figured out automatically.

Comment: @Reneux The question doesn't really accurately reflect your problem, so I don't think it's answerable in its current state. In any case, happy your problem is solved.

Comment: Note also that it's generally preferable to make your `commandList` a constructor parameter instead of a field; this avoids quite a few possible sequencing bugs and makes it more likely that errors will be reported immediately instead of later in the application's execution.